# How to represent $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_{kn}z^{kn}$ in terms of $f(z) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}z^{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Given a power series $f(z) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{n}$ where $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and radius of convergence $R.$ Then my goal is to find, 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{kn}z^{kn}$$
for $|z|<R$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}.$

So I tried two examples and I think there is a connection with roots of unity.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n}z^{2n} &=\frac{1}{2}(f(z)+f(i^2z))\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{3n}z^{3n} &=\frac{1}{2}(f(z)+f(iz) + f(i^2z))
\end{align*}
My guess is that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{kn}z^{kn} =\frac{1}{2}(f(z)+f(iz) + f(i^2z)+ \cdots + f(i^{k-1}z))$$
if $k$ is odd. For $k$ even I am not sure. Any generalizations of this fact or proof ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is $n$? An integer? A number ranging from $-\infty$ up to $\infty$? Or just starting by $0$ up to $\infty$?

Comment: Starting from $0$ and upto infinity.

Comment: Your formula for $\sum a_{3n} z^{3n}$ is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\omega \ne 1$ be a $k$-th root of unity: $\omega^k = 1$. Then
$$
 \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \omega^{nj} = \begin{cases}
k & \text{ if $n$ is a multiple of $k$,} \\
0 & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Consequently,
$$
 \frac 1k \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} f(\omega^j z ) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{kn}z^{kn}
$$

For $k=2$ this gives your result
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n}z^{2n} =\frac{1}{2}(f(z)+f(-z))\\
$$
For $k=3$ the correct result is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{3n}z^{3n} =\frac{1}{3}(f(z)+f(\omega z) + f(\omega^2 z))
$$
with $\omega = - \frac 12 \pm \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$.